# Configuring Proxmox Cluster Storage

Tags: virtualization, cluster, high-availability, partition, proxmox

We are configuring proxmox on our servers at two locations

each location has;

1 x hp c7000 enclosures with 16 blades 
1 x hp proliant dl585

We also plan to add a 24TB SAN to each location.

We are going to setup up two clusters per location, with the c7000 as a HA cluster that can failover to the other blades.

Each blade in the c7000 has 1x 1TB hdd, the default proxmox install takes up the majority of the space for the vz dumps. I want to partition the hdds at install and leave the proxmox install at around 50GB on one partition, and leave another partition to use as DRBD storage.

I can run this at boot install to set the proxmox install details
Linux ext4 maxroot=20 swapsize=30

if i add the flag
minfree=nGB

Will this create another partition i can configure as DRBD storage?

there is also this flag
maxvz=nGB

That sets the maximum data directory partition, how do i configure proxmox not to store data dumps on the local partition and only on the DRDB storage?

Thanks